# Move values out of an object

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a mongo collection that looks like this.

```
[{
    "name": "foo",
    "place": "Paris",
    "other": {
        "var1": "asdf",
        "var2": "asdf",
        "var3": "sdfw",
        etc....
    }
},{
    "name": "Bar",
    "place": "Paris",
    "other": {
        "var1": "asdf",
        "var2": "asdf",
        etc....
    }
}]
```

I need to have the data displayed as follows:

```
  [{
        "name": "foo",
        "place": "Paris",
        "var1": "asdf",
        "var2": "asdf",
        "var3": "sdfw",
        etc...
    },{
        "name": "Bar",
        "place": "Paris",
        "var1": "asdf",
        "var2": "asdf",
        etc....
    }]
```

So I want the object Other to be removed but keep al the values inside.
What is the best way to achieve this.
I can use Python3 or mongo aggregations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You  can use below [**`aggregation`**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TYHK9K0SPTs) using [**`$replaceRoot`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) and [**`$mergeObjects`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": { "$mergeObjects": ["$other", "$$ROOT"] }
  }},
  { "$project": { "other": 0 }}
])
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing it in Python is technically possible and rather simple:

```
for obj in collection:
    obj.update(obj.pop("other"))
```

but it *should* be faster to leave it to mongodb as explained in Anthony Winzlet's answer.

Comment: Never thought in a such way. Just awesome!